# Rewrite rules for Development & Production Environments

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I'm having trouble with the file path when I upload my development environment to the server.

The problem is actually quite simple.
Development is working on the root folder ( development.tld )
Production  is working on the sub-folder ( production.tld/**sub-folder** )

When I **manually** add a image in node content on the development environment, the path to that file is `/sites/default/files/test.jpg`

That path will not work in the production environment because of the sub-folder.

**Sample node content:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <img alt="test 1" src="/sites/default/files/test1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <img alt="test 2" src="/sites/default/files/test2.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

`RewriteBase /sub-folder` method works properly in general but I need to remap requests for the manually added assets 
`( /sites/default/files/* to /sub-folder/sites/default/files/* )`

Is there a Rewrite rules for this process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing (or assigning) the base url in sites/default/settings.php

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path of **public file system path**,

Navigate to `example.com/admin/config/media/file-system`

[image]